# como posso pegar um item selecionado de uma flatlist e passar para outra flat list?

Tags: react-native

import React,{useState, useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import { View, Text, Platform, SafeAreaView, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard, Alert, } from 'react-native';
import {format} from 'date-fns';
import { Container, ListPiscinasRecebidas, ListPedidoPiscinas, Title, TitlePedido, TextPiscinaValor, ButtonAddPiscina, FecharPedidoButton, FecharPedidoText } from './styles';

import {AuthContextLojista} from '../../contextsLojista/authLojista';
import firebase from '../../services/firebaseConnection';

import Header from '../../componentsFabrica/headerFabrica';
import PickerLojista from '../../componentsLojista/pickerLojista/index.android';
import ListaDePiscina from './ListaDePiscina';
import ListaPedidoPiscinas from './ListaPedidoPiscina';

export default function FazerPedido(){
const { userLojista: usuarioLojista } = useContext(AuthContextLojista);
const { userLojista } = useContext(AuthContextLojista);
const uid = userLojista && userLojista.uid;

```
const [selecioneFabrica, setSelecioneFabrica] = useState(null);

const [valor, setValor] = useState('');
const [nomeDaPiscina, setNomeDaPiscina] = useState([
    { key: '1', nomeDaPiscina: 'Italianaa', valor: 1111 },
    { key: '2', nomeDaPiscina: 'Italianaa2', valor: 1111 },
    { key: '3', nomeDaPiscina: 'Italianaa3', valor: 1111 },
    { key: '4', nomeDaPiscina: 'Italianaa4', valor: 1111 },
    { key: '5', nomeDaPiscina: 'Italianaa4', valor: 1111 },
    { key: '6', nomeDaPiscina: 'Italianaa4', valor: 1111 },
    { key: '7', nomeDaPiscina: 'Italianaa4', valor: 1111 },
    { key: '8', nomeDaPiscina: 'Italianaa4', valor: 1111 },
    { key: '9', nomeDaPiscina: 'Italianaa4', valor: 1111 },
    { key: '10', nomeDaPiscina: 'Italianaa4', valor: 1111 },
    { key: '11', nomeDaPiscina: 'Italianaa4', valor: 1111 },
    { key: '12', nomeDaPiscina: 'Italianaa4', valor: 1111 },
    { key: '13', nomeDaPiscina: 'Italianaa4', valor: 1111 },
    { key: '14', nomeDaPiscina: 'Italianaa4', valor: 1111 },
]);


function handleSelectPiscina(data) {
    Alert.alert(
        'Cuidado preste Atenção!',
        `Você deseja Adicionar ${data.nomeDaPiscina} - Valor: ${data.valor}`,
        [
            {
                text: 'Cancelar',
                style: 'cancel'
            },
            {
                text: 'Continuar',
                onPress: () => handleSelect(data)
            }
        ]

    )
}

function handleSelect(){
    
}



    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=> Keyboard.dismiss()}>
        <Container>
            <Header />
            <Title>{userLojista && userLojista.nomeDaLoja} </Title>
            <SafeAreaView>
                    <PickerLojista onChange={setSelecioneFabrica} selecioneFabrica={selecioneFabrica} />
            </SafeAreaView>

            <Title>Piscinas da Fabrica</Title>
            <ListPiscinasRecebidas
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            data={nomeDaPiscina}
            keyExtractor={item=> item.key}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (<ListaDePiscina data={item} handleSelect={handleSelectPiscina}/>)}
            />

             <TitlePedido>Meu Pedido</TitlePedido>
            <ListPedidoPiscinas
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    data={handleSelect}
                    keyExtractor={item => item}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (<ListaPedidoPiscinas data={item} handleSelect={data} />)}

            />
                <FecharPedidoButton>
                    <FecharPedidoText>Fechar Pedido</FecharPedidoText>
                </FecharPedidoButton>
        </Container>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `onPress` e guarde o item no state.

```
// no Componente da lista ...

renderItem={({ item }) => {
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleSelectList(item)}>
   <ListaDePiscina data={item} handleSelect={handleSelectPiscina}/>
  </TouchableOpacity>
 }
}

// ...
```

Ou dentro do componente `<ListaDePiscina />`, adicione um componente (ex. TouchableOpacity) que tenha onPress em sua prop.

Na função em `onPress`, receba o `item` que foi pressionado e manipule para adicionar em uma nova lista no state que tenha os itens que selecionados.

Obs.: No código de exemplo a função `handleSelectList(item)` não foi criada. Mas ela deveria fazer algo como:

- Receber os itens que anteriormente foram selecionados (opcional, depende do seu objetivo);
- Adicionar os itens recebidos com o novo item;
- Setar os dados manipulados a cima no state.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, estou tentando resolver isso tem muito tempo e não tenho conseguido, tentei fazer da maneira que você falou mas não consegui

Comment: no momento estou ocupado com o trabalho, mas executo o código por cá para podermos solucionar, caso ainda não tenha conseguido.

Comment: tudo bem, me desculpa incomodar, é que estou com muita dificuldade mesmo e eu gostaria de resolver isso, mas eu acho que é avançado demais pra mim.